# If muons had long enough half lives, could muon-catalyzed p-p fusion be viable?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

I was reading about muon-catalyzed fusion and how the "alpha sticking problem" is a major barrier to viability, but when you fuse two protons together you get deuterium instead, which still only has one proton. So with p-p fusion the "alpha sticking problem" wouldn't be a major barrier. However, muon-catalysed p-p fusion isn't viable due to the short half-life of the muons relative to the fusion rate.

But if the half-life of a muon were on the order of seconds, minutes or longer, could p-p muon-catalyzed fusion be viable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your model of physics is that there is a dial labeled “muon lifetime” which you can turn without changing anything else, then sure, probably.

But of course that’s not how our model of particle physics works. For example, the muon lifetime is a famous piece of evidence for the universal coupling of the weak charged current, with lifetime $\tau$ obeying ([see e.g.](https://157.physics.ucdavis.edu/sites/157.physics.ucdavis.edu/files/files/Muon%20Lifetime/cosmic_ray_guide_2012.pdf))

$$
\frac\hbar\tau = \Gamma = \frac{G_F^2 m_\mu^5}{192\pi^3}
$$

If your dial to shorten the muon lifetime is to make the muon less massive, then you have a computation to do about whether the less-massive muon would still produce a muonic molecule small enough for the fusion catalysis to be effective.  But if your dial to shorten the muon lifetime is to make the Fermi coupling constant $G_F$ feebler, then you would also have more neutrons participating in Big Bang nucleosynthesis in the first hour of the Universe, substantially different stellar chemistry, and a real chance of a universe with no people in it to build nuclear reactors of any type. Counterfactual questions are *hard.*

Note that p-p fusion to deuterium is a weak-interaction process, whose cross section is too low to observe in any terrestrial experiment.  Muon-catalyzed fusion is d-d or d-t fusion, where the strong interaction permits a neutron to escape from the nucleus; the weak interaction is not involved (apart from the muon decay).

Comment: jeez man! how can you possibly know all this stuff?? Most impressive...

Comment: " a dial labeled “muon lifetime” which you can turn " - thank god not, or all the stars would have burned out billions of years ago. You'd only need a few to catalyze everything.